# UICollectionView crashes when column count changes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionview` and the number of columns are changing randomly. Every time the column count changes I invoke the following function.

```
func setTheCollectionViewSize(){



    if self.activeLockerList.count > 0 {
        self.btnLockerDropdown.setTitle("Lockers Set \(self.activeLockerList[0].lockerId)", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height


    //if the collection view layout is not invalidated then the app will crash


    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    //setting the collectionview size so there will be no white lines in the drawn boxes
    var appropriateScreenWidth = Int(self.screenWidth)
    while appropriateScreenWidth % Int(self.numberOfLockersPerColumn) != 0 {
        appropriateScreenWidth = appropriateScreenWidth - 1
    }

    let itemWidth : CGFloat = CGFloat(appropriateScreenWidth) / self.numberOfLockersPerColumn
    collectionViewWidthLocal.constant = CGFloat(appropriateScreenWidth)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    print(self.numberOfLockersPerColumn)
    print(screenWidth)

    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 0, bottom: 10.0, right: 0)

    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

    self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)

}
```

When the cell count for each row increases it works fine. But when the count decreases app crashes at the line `self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)`

As you can see invalidating the collectionview with `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` also didn't help. I've been spending hours and hours still without luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` should help you out. It weird it didn't work. Let's wait and see the answer from community.

Comment: Where exactly does the crash happen? What is the crashes output/error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you invoke `setTheCollectionViewSize()` function before `collectionView.reloadData()` or after?

It should go in the following order. Try and let me know.

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
self.setTheCollectionViewSize()
```

in other words following should be the order when invalidating collectionview

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

Hope it helps you out.